# R Question Number of Unique Combinations of A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B

Tags: r, combinations

I am trying to find a way to get a list in R of all the possible unique permutations of A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B.

Combinations was what was originally thought to be the method for obtaining a solution,  hence the combinations answers.

Comment: perhaps `?combn` is what you are after?

Comment: good start but the combn function requires you to choose m at a time.  I just was looking for all the unique combinations of the above string......not a subset.  Perhaps I am not thinking about this right either.

Comment: You might try both `?unique` and `?combn`.

Comment: Gotcha. Question for ya - still thinking in the combn mindset, are the values returned by `combn(x, 2)` that are all `A A` considered redundant?

Comment: Is this the same as [Permute all unique enumerations of a vector in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671149/permute-all-unique-enumerations-of-a-vector-in-r)?

Comment: Seems to be the same to me, though it's quite a bit simpler because there are only two possible values in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're after. @bill was on the ball with the recommendation of combining `unique` and `combn`. We'll also use the apply family to generate ALL of the combinations. Since `unique` removes duplicate rows, we need to transpose the results from `combn` before `unique`ing them. We then transpose them back before returning to the screen so that each column represents a unique answer.

```
#Daters
x <- c(rep("A", 4), rep("B",5))
#Generates a list with ALL of the combinations
zz <- sapply(seq_along(x), function(y) combn(x,y))
#Filter out all the duplicates
sapply(zz, function(z) t(unique(t(z))))
```

Which returns:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
[2,] "A"  "B"  "B" 

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "B" 
[2,] "A"  "A"  "B"  "B" 
[3,] "A"  "B"  "B"  "B" 

...
```

**EDIT** Since the question is about permuations and not combinations, the answer above is not that useful. [This post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/permutations-in-R-td884599.html) outlines a function to generate the unique permutations given a set of parameters. I have no idea if it could be improved upon, but here's one approach using that function:

```
fn_perm_list <-
 function (n, r, v = 1:n)
 {
    if (r == 1)
       matrix(v, n, 1)
    else if (n == 1)
       matrix(v, 1, r)
    else {
       X <- NULL
       for (i in 1:n) X <- rbind(X, cbind(v[i], fn_perm_list(n -
            1, r - 1, v[-i])))
        X
    }
 } 

zz <- fn_perm_list(9, 9)

#Turn into character matrix. This currently does not generalize well, but gets the job done
zz <- ifelse(zz <= 4, "A", "B")

#Returns 126 rows as indicated in comments
unique(zz)
```

Comment: What I have really done here is mistaken permutation with combination. Order in this case matters and in that situation i believe there are 9!/(4!*5!) = 126 different permutations of AAAABBBBB. Some examples of the permuations would be: AAABBBBBA , AAABBBBAB , AAAABBBABB , AAAABBABBB , and so on –.  Could we modify that code Chase to get us there?

Comment: @RyanB - updated answer to address your comment. There appears to be some good information in the link I referenced which may be more efficient than the function I grabbed.

Comment: @RyanB - you can also update your question with this information and the title as well.

Comment: @RyanB: If Chase nailed it, please select his answer so that it is easier for others to see that.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to generate permutations and then pick out the unique ones.
Here's a much simpler way (and much, much faster as well): To generate all permutations of 4 A's and 5 B's, we just need to enumerate all possible ways of placing 4 A's among 9 possible locations. This is simply a combinations problem. Here's how we can do this:

```
x <- rep('B',9) # vector of 9 B's

a_pos <- combn(9,4) # all possible ways to place 4 A's among 9 positions

perms <- apply(a_pos, 2, function(p) replace(x,p,'A')) # all desired permutations
```

Each column of the 9x126 matrix `perms` is a unique permutation 4 A's and 5 B's:

```
> dim(perms)
[1]   9 126
> perms[,1:4] ## look at first few columns
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
 [2,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
 [3,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
 [4,] "A"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
 [5,] "B"  "A"  "B"  "B" 
 [6,] "B"  "B"  "A"  "B" 
 [7,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "A" 
 [8,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
 [9,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"
```