# R: generate all permutations of vector without duplicated elements

Tags: r

Is there a straightforward way to generate all possible permutations of a vector of integers (1 to max 999) that specifically excludes duplicated elements?

For example, for a vector with three elements in a range of 1 to 9 the sequence `1 2 3` would be acceptable, as would `1 2 9` but `1 2 2` would be invalid. The sequence must contain exactly `n` elements (in this case, three). EDIT: to avoid confusion, the order is significant, so `1 2 9` and `9 2 1` are both valid and required.

There are many questions on permutations and combinations using R on SO (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422945/generate-all-possible-permutations) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084947/how-to-generate-all-combinations-of-a-vector)) but none that seem to fit this particular case. I'm hoping there's an obscure base R or package function out there that will take care of it without me having to write a graceless function myself.

Comment: Yes, the order is important as well as the elements themselves.

Comment: Well, the answer without the edited clarification was surely `sample` and I'm sure this is a duplicate, but the cited duplicate is not a good answer.

Comment: As a warning to those who follow: the number of permutations of `n` items is `n!`, which gets big really fast. For the 999 elements mentioned in this question there are about 4 * 10^2564 permutations.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, as the linked question does not actually ask about permutations, despite having this word in its title.

Comment: This question also does not seem to be just about permutations. `1 2 9` is not a permutation of `1 2 3`. The question is unclear to me, though. What role does 999 have? Is this the question? For some set S (say, integers from 1 to 9) and some positive integer n, how can I get all unique vectors of n elements such that each element is in S?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using `gtools` package:

```
require(gtools)
permutations(n = 9, r = 3, v = 1:9)
# n -> size of source vector
# r -> size of target vector
# v -> source vector, defaults to 1:n
# repeats.allowed = FALSE (default)
```

Answer (score 12):

`utils::combn`  ;   `combinat::combn` or `combinat::permn`  are alternatives.

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT: This is not what the OP asked for, but I leave this answer, to avoid confusion.**

My math is a little bit rusty, but i think you are describing combinations, not permutations. The base function`combn()` returns combinations.

I illustrate with a manageable set - all combinations of length 3, from the vector `1:4`:

```
combn(4, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    3    3
[3,]    3    4    4    4
```

---

The difference between `combinations` and `permutations` is that in `combinations` the order doesn't matter. So, `(2, 3, 4)` and `(4, 3, 2)` is the same combination, but different permutations.

Comment: This is not all possible permutations, is it? ex: (4,3,2) isn't here...?

Comment: @Andrie I'm certain my math is rustier. But doesn't the above require a check after generation to remove duplicates? Or should I be reading down the columns rather than across the rows of the matrix above?

Comment: @SlowLearner, you should read down columns. So, you were looking for combinations..?

Comment: @Arun But the order is also significant. So `2 3 4` and `4 3 2` are different but both are required.

Comment: @SlowLearner, that is what my answer gives, but this is just combinations.