# Combinatorially rearrange the contents of list values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose i have several values

```
d1,d2,d3,d4,d5
```

How can I swap them in this format?

```
d2,d1,d3,d4,d5
d3,d2,d1,d4,d5
d4,d1,d2,d3,d5
d5,d1,d2,d3,d4.
```

In other words, each subsequent value from a series of values ​​becomes the first, and other, in order, follow it.
When there are few values, i can do it manually, but if there are hundreds of them, it is much more difficult.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want all permutations of a vector? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704039/r-generate-all-permutations-of-vector-without-duplicated-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setdiff`

```
t(sapply(x, function(u) c(u, setdiff(x, u))))
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
d1 "d1" "d2" "d3" "d4" "d5"
d2 "d2" "d1" "d3" "d4" "d5"
d3 "d3" "d1" "d2" "d4" "d5"
d4 "d4" "d1" "d2" "d3" "d5"
d5 "d5" "d1" "d2" "d3" "d4"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("d1","d2","d3","d4","d5")
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you don't want all permutations or even all possible n-way combinations.  Here is one way to do it.

```
x <- c("d1","d2","d3","d4","d5")
t(sapply(1:length(x), function(i)x[c(i, (1:length(x))[-i])]))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] "d1" "d2" "d3" "d4" "d5"
# [2,] "d2" "d1" "d3" "d4" "d5"
# [3,] "d3" "d1" "d2" "d4" "d5"
# [4,] "d4" "d1" "d2" "d3" "d5"
# [5,] "d5" "d1" "d2" "d3" "d4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something "fun" to try using `SOfun` package. Result left as a list.

```
# source("http://news.mrdwab.com/install_github.R")
# install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")

library(SOfun)

vec <- paste0("d", 1:5)

sapply(
  vec,
  \(x) moveMe(vec, paste(x, "first")),
  simplify = F
)
```

**Output**

```
$d1
[1] "d1" "d2" "d3" "d4" "d5"

$d2
[1] "d2" "d1" "d3" "d4" "d5"

$d3
[1] "d3" "d1" "d2" "d4" "d5"

$d4
[1] "d4" "d1" "d2" "d3" "d5"

$d5
[1] "d5" "d1" "d2" "d3" "d4"
```