# Creating a permutation of a length 40 vector of boolean values in R

Tags: algorithm, r, permutation

I am trying to create the unique permutations of the vector

```
 c(rep(0,20),rep(1,20))
```

but permn in the combinat package says "Error in vector.... vector size specified is too large".

I also tried the script uniqueperm2 from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671149/permute-all-unique-enumerations-of-a-vector-in-r) and got a "vector specified is too large" error again.

In my understanding permn would be creating 40! permutations.

I might be able to solve the overall problem I am working on just by finding the number of unique permutations of this vector.

Is the problem of finding the unique permutations of a length 40 vector too big for R and can anyone explain to me how to figure out the number of unique permutations of the listed vector?

Answer (score 2):

Each unique permutation of this vector corresponds to a subset of size 20 from {1, 2, ..., 40} (i.e, the indices of the 1s).

The number of these subsets is "40 choose 20", or 40! / (20! x 20!).  According to Google calculator this equals 137,846,528,820

Answer (score 1):

As you have already been told, the number of permutations can be computed as:

```
R> choose(40,20)
[1] 137846528820
```

However, the longest vector that R can currently handle is 2^31 - 1 elements long, which is:

```
R> 2^31 - 1
[1] 2147483647
```

which is way smaller than the number of permutations you want to generate. Hence the errors you are getting and the error you;d get if you tried this with the standard function to generate these permutations `combn()`:

```
R> combn(40, 20)
Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In combn(40, 20) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

At this point you'll have to resort to writing code to generate the permutations in a bath-like manner and investigate one of the many big-data packages on R (see the [High Performance Computing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) task view).

Or, and this would be my **suggestion**, consider what you are possibly going to be able to do with 137 billion! (American) permutations and then take another approach. If you could deal with 1 per second (i.e. do something meaningful with the permutation that took 1 second) you'd still be working on the results in 4000 years time!

So why do you want all the permutations? Would a smaller random set suffice?

Comment: It was for a problem dealing with the number of routes from the top left corner of a 20x20 square area to the bottom right corner with no backtracking making 1unit moves at a time. I wanted to generate the routes {1,22,...,441} for example.  But since the number is so large I'll settle for just know the number of routes.

Answer (score 0):

There are (40 choose 20) unique permutations (i.e. choose 20 of the 40 positions for the `0`s and use the other 20 for the `1`s.) That's still quite a large number, but you could try combn(40, 20)

Comment: Not in any R I am familiar with, except perhaps bits of R Devel currently. The longest vector in R currently is 2^31 - 1 elements long. `combn(40,20)` would yield `choose(40,20)` combinations (actually it would yield a vector of total length `2 * choose(40,20)` as it stores the result as a matrix. This is far, far too big to be handled by R's tools currently.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: indeed. I should have computed the actual value. Still, it's only huge. By the way, I'd be surprised if it takes R a whole second to do anything meaningful with 20 numbers, even given what I've heard about R's lack of speed. If you could do something meaningful with each permutation in a microsecond -- like toss it out of consideration -- then you could get through the lot in a couple of days, and that's without any parallelization at all. (Oh, and it's 0.138 yanqui trillion. fwiw)

Comment: @rico thanks for pointing out that I can't count. Fixed now. As for other part; yes, there are ways round this and parallel processing will help, as will the on disk storage options. I was being conservative with the time per permutation  assuming a non trivial computation. R is generally quite quick; sometimes user friendliness gets in way though.