# All combinations of specific numbers with specific length in R

Tags: r, vector, combinations

I have the numbers `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`.

I want to create all the vectors of length `14`, such that the number `1` appears `4` times, `2` appears `3` times, `3` appears `5` times and `4` appears `2` times, that is:

`4` times + `3` times + `5` times + `2` times = length `14`.

For example, three of these vectors are:

`1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4`

`1,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4`

`1,1,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4`

and so on.

I have tried to use `combn` but it was not successful.

The number of these vector is equal to `choose(14,4)*choose(14-4,3)*choose(14-4-3,5)*choose(14-4-3-5,2)`.

**EDIT**

Using `permn(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4))`, I will create, for example the vector `1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4` many times, that is I will have duplicated vectors. Then I have to use `unique`. But it is not worth creating duplicated vectors and then to keep the unique ones, since I want only the unique ones, that is the vector `1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4` just one time.

So, the answer in question [Generating all distinct permutations of a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095992/generating-all-distinct-permutations-of-a-list-in-r) creates duplicated vectors.

Comment: *"create all the vectors"* Unless I misunderstood, that'll be *a lot* (!) of combinations. Do you really want to create *all* combinations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095992/generating-all-distinct-permutations-of-a-list-in-r

Comment: With `library(combinat)`you can use e.g. `unique(permn(c(1,1,2,2,3,3)))`. But with the length of you vectors you exceed the memory limit...

Comment: @user2974951 `permn` creates duplicated vectors.

Comment: @Arienrhod `permn` created duplicated vectors.

Comment: @Chelmy88 I think that I do not have to do this, because of the memory limit as you correctly stated.

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis Let's call your vector `x <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4)`; you do realise that there are `factorial(length(x))/prod(factorial(table(x)))` or `2522520` combinations? Just in terms of memory, that would be quite significant (around 0.5 Gb if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @MauritsEvers Of course, I know it. But I have to create them.

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis Take a look at the dupe target link, which should address your question. If your issue is in fact a different one, please let me know and I'll re-open.

Comment: @MauritsEvers my question is duplicated. The answer is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671149/permute-all-unique-enumerations-of-a-vector-in-r.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I would argue that the more canonical dupe target is https://stackoverflow.com/q/22569176/4408538

Comment: @JosephWood Added & thanks.